# Runtime excecute command wont end

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am running this code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("explorer");
rt = null;
```

The code runs and do the job, but the program dont terminate - that is the red light (using Eclipse IDE) is still on meaning the program didnt ended.

What may be the problem>

Comment: how about you use the debugger?

Comment: what happens if you close the explorer instance that it starts?

Comment: Isn't the `explorer` process forked from the java process? Java will remain running until explorer ends.

Comment: @DaveHowes The program end! So how do i make the program end without terminating the created instance?

Comment: I've run your code, it terminates immediately (not depending on explorer being closed or not).

Comment: @MichaelA Call `destroy()` on the process object returned by `exec()`.

Comment: I am using Java on Windows, Waybe you are using diffrent OS?

Comment: Windows + IDEA + java 1.7, try to relaunch your project (refresh) and try again

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Destroy end the program but also kill the process that exec created :-

Comment: If you want to exit without stopping the process, `System.exit(0);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, assigning null to something in Java doesn't make it stop or go away.  At best, it *may* make whatever it is unreachable ... and hence eligible for garbage collection at some point in the future.

If you want to stop an external process you need to call [`destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) on the `Process` object.  This will attempt to forcibly terminate the external child process.  Whether it will succeed will depend on the application's privilege. (Whether this will terminate all of the child processes descendants depends on the platform ... )

---

You commented thus:

> "Destroy end the program but also kill the process that exec created ..."

Well, if you don't want to kill the process, and just want to know what is going on, then the explanation is that the "red light" *means* that the child process is still running.  If you want the "red-light" to go away without killing the child process, you are probably out of luck.

I guess, the other possibility is that you actually want the child process to "detach" from the Java application.  I don't know how you would do this in Windows, but in Unix / Linux you'd launch it like this:

```
 /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/firefox &"
```

The `&` says run in the background, and the `nohup` detaches standard input / output / error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to move the call to runtime.exec into a separate Runnable object. When you create the Thread to start this runnable, set it as a daemon. The JVM should close, but leave the daemon thread running.

Answer (score 0):

So exec from Java will launch the explorer with out ending...

One solution is simply tell the Java to run a batch file which run Explorer.